# Can't Able to get Instance of ExceptionManager

Tags: silverlight-4.0, exception, enterprise-library, mvvm-light

I am using Enterprise Library 5.0 in Silverlight using mvvm-light Framework.
When I'm going to getInstace of ExceptionManager Class like:

```
 var exceptionManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>();
  exceptionManager.HandleException(E.Error, "Policy");
```

I Got this type of error Message

```
Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ExceptionManager, key ""

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManager", name = "(none)"
  Exception occurred while: while resolving.Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type TraceListener cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value
 -----------------------------------------------
 At the time of the exception, the container was:

 Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManagerImpl,ExceptionManager.__default__ (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManager, (none))
Resolving parameter "exceptionPolicies" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManagerImpl(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Silverlight, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] exceptionPolicies, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Instrumentation.IDefaultExceptionHandlingInstrumentationProvider instrumentationProvider)
Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl,Policy
Resolving parameter "policyEntries" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl(System.String policyName, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyEntry, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Silverlight, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] policyEntries)
  Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyEntry,Policy.All Exceptions
  Resolving parameter "handlers" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyEntry(System.Type exceptionType, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.PostHandlingAction postHandlingAction, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Silverlight, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] handlers, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Instrumentation.IExceptionHandlingInstrumentationProvider instrumentationProvider)
    Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler,Policy.All Exceptions.Logging Exception Handler (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler, Policy.All Exceptions.Logging Exception Handler)
    Resolving parameter "writer" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler(System.String logCategory, System.Int32 eventId, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Diagnostics.TraceEventType severity, System.String title, System.Int32 priority, System.Type formatterType, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter writer)
      Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl,LogWriter.__default__ (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter, (none))
      Resolving parameter "structureHolder" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder structureHolder, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider instrumentationProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.IAsyncTracingErrorReporter asyncTracingErrorReporter)
        Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder,LogWriterStructureHolder.__default__ (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder, (none))
        Resolving parameter "traceSources" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.ILogFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Silverlight, Version=5.0.505.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] filters, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] traceSourceNames, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Silverlight, Version=5.0.505.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] traceSources, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource allEventsTraceSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource notProcessedTraceSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource errorsTraceSource, System.String defaultCategory, System.Boolean tracingEnabled, System.Boolean logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch, System.Boolean revertImpersonation)
          Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource,General
          Resolving parameter "traceListeners" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource(System.String name, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Diagnostics.TraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Silverlight, Version=5.0.505.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] traceListeners, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Diagnostics.SourceLevels level, System.Boolean autoFlush, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider instrumentationProvider)
            Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Diagnostics.TraceListener,Flat File Trace Listener
```

At Line of

```
 var exceptionManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>();
```

My Configuration File is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ResourceDictionary           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:el="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2011/entlib">
     <el:ExceptionHandlingSettings x:Key="exceptionHandling">
     <el:ExceptionHandlingSettings.ExceptionPolicies>
     <el:ExceptionPolicyData Name="LogPolicy">
     <el:ExceptionPolicyData.ExceptionTypes>
      <el:ExceptionTypeData Name="All Exceptions" TypeName="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e">
        <el:ExceptionTypeData.ExceptionHandlers>
          <el:LoggingExceptionHandlerData LogCategory="General" FormatterTypeName="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Silverlight, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Priority="-1" Name="Logging Exception Handler" />
        </el:ExceptionTypeData.ExceptionHandlers>
      </el:ExceptionTypeData>
    </el:ExceptionPolicyData.ExceptionTypes>
  </el:ExceptionPolicyData>
 </el:ExceptionHandlingSettings.ExceptionPolicies>
 </el:ExceptionHandlingSettings>
 <el:LoggingSettings DefaultCategory="General" x:Key="loggingConfiguration">
  <el:LoggingSettings.TraceSources>
  <el:TraceSourceData Name="General">
    <el:TraceSourceData.TraceListeners>
      <el:TraceListenerReferenceData Name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </el:TraceSourceData.TraceListeners>
  </el:TraceSourceData>
 </el:LoggingSettings.TraceSources>
 <el:LoggingSettings.SpecialTraceSources>
  <el:SpecialTraceSourcesData>
    <el:SpecialTraceSourcesData.AllEventsTraceSource>
      <el:TraceSourceData Name="All Events" />
    </el:SpecialTraceSourcesData.AllEventsTraceSource>
    <el:SpecialTraceSourcesData.NotProcessedTraceSource>
      <el:TraceSourceData Name="Unprocessed Category" />
    </el:SpecialTraceSourcesData.NotProcessedTraceSource>
    <el:SpecialTraceSourcesData.ErrorsTraceSource>
      <el:TraceSourceData Name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <el:TraceSourceData.TraceListeners>
          <el:TraceListenerReferenceData Name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </el:TraceSourceData.TraceListeners>
      </el:TraceSourceData>
    </el:SpecialTraceSourcesData.ErrorsTraceSource>
  </el:SpecialTraceSourcesData>
  </el:LoggingSettings.SpecialTraceSources>
  </el:LoggingSettings>
  </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration?  It looks like the Exception Handling Block is using Logging but the Logging Trace Listener can't be found (in the configuration).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your configuration is referencing a trace listener called "Flat File Trace Listener" but there is no trace listener defined by that name.

Also, you should be aware that the Enterprise Library Silverlight Logging Application Block does not support a Flat File Trace Listener. Valid actions are:

- Logging to a remote WCF Service.
- Logging to isolated storage.
- Logging to an event.

Comment: But it gives me same error when i'm going to add Logging Block. When I  removed the loggingBlock the ExceptionHandling works fine. But when I want to Log the exception what can I do?